# How to save and load a PDF into memory stream using Spire PDF C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, spire.doc

```
public MemoryStream PdfGeneration(Model model)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.pdf");
    path = path.Replace("\\api", "");
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    doc.SaveToStream(fs);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.SetLength(fs.Length);
    fs.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fs.Length);
    ms.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    return ms;
}
```

PS: I don't want the file to be read from the disk, it has to be processed in memory.

So here I am using Spire `PDF` as a generator and I need to save it to memory stream and send as an attachment to mail.

Answer (score 2):

To load file from stream, you can use LoadFromStream method

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromStream(Stream stream);
```